# Why is trivial implicit not found?

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, implicits

Why isn't the implicit not found, even in something as trivial as:

```
class Wrapper[+A](data: Vector[A]) {
  def sum[B >: A](implicit num: Numeric[B]) = data.sum
}
```

won't compile, without resorting to manually passing in `num` to `data.sum`

Comment: With ``data.sum[B]`` it works. Looks as if type inference is the problem, but why, I can't say.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but as a workaround you could move the implicit argument to the `Wrapper` constructor (it's intended to match the type `Vector[A]` after all).

Comment: The problems seems that data.sum is polymorphic as well... can you provide more details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

§7.2 of [Scala specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) (page 107) states that `implicit parameters are inferred after any type arguments are inferred`. I believe this is the problem.

Typer infers most specific parameter for `data.sum` - `A`, and then looks for implicit `Numeric[A]` in scope. He can't substitute it with `Numeric[B]` because `Numeric` is invariant.

Comment: Sadly, `Numeric` ought to be contra-variant.